# Adding additional horizontal bar to barplot in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I hope this is no duplicate, I couldn't find anything like this anywhere. So here it goes:

I found a plot in a paper that indicates both activity as well as data availability, see the

[image: top bar with grey shaded areas here]

(where grey indicates no data), and I was wondering if this is somehow possible in R / ggplot?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.

Regarding duplicate: I am sure this will have been asked before, and someone might find a duplicate. But don't worry too much about this - this is a good thing. It will help broaden the search terms for questions and guide people to the right answer. Anyways. I haven't found a quick one for this so here one option.

Regarding reproducibility: It generally helps and would be great to have some data to play with, rather than to have to create it ourselves. See below for an example how I did it.

You need to create a data frame for the segment annotation first, I am using run length encoding from data.table. If you wonder about the "x +/- 0.5", try removing the 0.5 and see what happens. It's just a quick hack to avoid the gap between the segments.

```r
library(tidyverse)

foo <- data.frame(
  date = seq.Date(as.Date("2021-01-01"), as.Date("2021-01-31"), by = "days"),
  count = rnorm(31, 4, 1))
foo$count[3:10] <- NA

# the answer starts here
# calculate data gaps
df_rect <- 
  foo %>% 
  mutate(nodata = is.na(count),
    rle_nodat = data.table::rleid(nodata)) %>%
  group_by(rle_nodat) %>%
  summarise(xmax = max(date), xmin = min(date), nodata = unique(nodata))
#> `summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)

ggplot(foo, aes(date, count)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_rect(data = df_rect, inherit.aes = FALSE,
            mapping = aes(xmin = xmin - 0.5, xmax = xmax + 0.5, 
                          ymin = 6, ymax = 6.5,
            fill = nodata)
  ) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(`FALSE` = "white", `TRUE` = "Grey50"))
#> Warning: Removed 8 rows containing missing values (position_stack).
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-01-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Brilliant, thanks so much, exactly what I needed!! And I will keep your tip about reproducible in mind for future posts :)